# Is there a way to know when a For each is on his first and last Iteration on genexus X v3?

Tags: genexus

I am using a for each to call a command that generates a report but I need the first and last report with somehow different data than the others, Is there a way to know this on genexus X v3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to discriminate the first iteration from the remaining ones you may just use a boolean variable. This can also be used when, in the last iteration, you need to do something **after** what you do in every other iteration:

```
&first = true
for each
  if &first
    &first = false
    // Do whatever you need in the first iteration
  else
    // Do whatever you need in the remaining iterations
  endif
endfor

// Do whatever you need to do after the last iteration
```

If you need to do something different in the last iteration **instead** of what you do for every other iteration you need to delay your action one iteration and use buffer variables to hold the previous values.

For example, suppose you need to use two attributes `CustomerCode`, `CustomerName` and you need to call `Procedure1` for the first iteration, `Procedure2` for the remaining less the last iteration and `Procedure3` for the last one:

```
&first = true
&rest = false
for each
  if &first
    &first = false
    // Do whatever you need in the first iteration
      Procedure1(CustomerCode, CustomerName)
  else
    if &rest
    // Do whatever you need in the remaining iterations, using buffer variables             
       Procedure2(&CustomerCode, &CustomerName)
    else
       &rest = true
    endif
    // Load buffer variables
    &CustomerCode = CustomerCode
    &CustomerName = CustomerName
  endif
endfor

// Do whatever you need in the last iteration, using buffer variables
if &rest
 Procedure3(&CustomerCode, &CustomerName)
endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer gusbro, but on the second " if "  the only iteration that is not taking is the second one, because "&rest" is false making it always do all the iterations at exception of the second one, it does manage to save the last data and to run the last procedure, but, it does it twice.

Comment: @r210: Have you tried the code ?. The first iteration enters in the first `if` and executes `Procedure1` with the first set of values. The second iteration enters the `else` part of the first `if` and enters the `else` part of the second `if` which just sets `&rest` to true, then loads the buffer variables. The remaining iterations enters the `else` part of the first `if` and enter the second `if` executing `Procedure2` with the buffer variables.

Comment: Then the buffer variables are updated. This continues until the last iteration, say iteration `N`, executes `Procedure2` with the values of iteration `N-1`, and this finishes the `for each` loop. Afterwards `Procedure3` is executed with the last buffer values (those of iteration `N`)

Comment: Yes I tested it, and as I wrote first it skips the 2nd iteration but it does because there is no procedure done on it, I fixed it just adding a procedure on the `else &rest = true` thank you it really help me out

Comment: @r210: The second iteration skips calling the procedure because it delays the execution one iteration. That is: Iteration 2 does not execute Procedure2, Iteration 3 executes Procedure2<2>, Iteration 4 executes Procedure2<3>, ..., iteration X executes Procedure2<X-1>. After finishing the for each (say it was iteration N) Procedure3<N> is executed.